# Always show AVPlayer controls

Tags: swift, avplayer, uicontrol, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an AVPlayerViewController with a AVPlayer in it, and what I need is that the controls of the player (play, pause, time slider) never hides. Right now after more or less 4 seconds of playing the video the become hidden, and you have to tap the screen to show them again. I haven't been able to find a solution to that.. any ideas? thx!

Comment: Finally I didn't find a solution so I create my own controls..

Answer (score 6):

You can set that by using [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html)

Swift:

```
 // playerController : AVPlayerViewController
 playerController.setValue(false, forKey: "canHidePlaybackControls")
```

Comment: Crashes on tvOS