# AVPlayerViewController - How to display always playback controls

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem

AVPlayerViewController, by default is auto-hides his playback controls.

is it possible to keep playback controls visible for good?

```
showsPlaybackControls = YES;
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660095/always-show-avplayer-controls

Comment: I meant to display "always"

Comment: that is exactly what is in the other question, you're looking for something to prevent auto-hiding controls! the same thing is there

Comment: Thank you @AmirKhorsandi, I'll test it √

Answer (score 2):

**That's not possible.** There is not any **Public API** of **AVPlayerViewController** to keep playback controls visible all time. You must have to make your own custom playback controls for this i.e. **play button**, **seekbar**, **duration label etc**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **player.showsPlaybackControls = true** it will show you the default playback controls.